# Span forming a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that the vectors 
>   $v_1=(1,1,1)$, $v_2=(1,1,0)$, $v_3=(1,0,0)$, $v_4=(3,2,0)$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$ but do not form a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^3$:

I understand how to find different find the general solution through RREF using the augmented matrix, 
but I do not understand how the arbitrary vector $x=(x,y,z)$ can be written as 
$x=zv_1+(y-z)v_2+(x-y)v_3+0v_4$

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your notation in your last statement. At any rate. To show that these are not linearly independent, just express one of them as a linear combination of the others.

Comment: I updated the question in case the format was comfusing, but I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: Okay maybe I understand what you're confused about. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll await for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about how to "discover" the answer. I'll show that below.

First of all, it should be obvious that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$. The question is how to prove it.

You need to prove that any $u=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ can be written in terms of $$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}, v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, v_3=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Clearly you can now see that we should choose $zv_1$ as part of our answer, because that's the only way to make the third component of the vectors be equal.

In maths notation, we want the coefficients $c_i$ such that

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = c_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}+ c_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+ c_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

In case you're unsure how to read this, this is actually three equations in the three unknowns $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$, like so:

$$x = c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 1 + c_3 \cdot 1$$
$$y = c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 1 + c_3 \cdot 0$$
$$z = c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_3 \cdot 0$$

Now can you complete the task?

Comment: Hey, come on, I was editing my answer! Don't downvote (whoever did that)!

Comment: i still don't understand how the answer came up with the letters in front of v1, v2, v3, v4 which is z, (y-z), (x-y), 0 respectively :/ also it wasn't me! i tried upvoting to make it 0

Comment: @chrissykwon edited answer. Can you understand now?

Comment: omg i got it !!!! thank you so much !!!!

Answer (score 2):

We have $ x=zv_{1}+(y-z)v_{2}+(x-y)v_{3}+0v_{4}=z(1,1,1)+(y-z)(1,1,0)+(x-y)(1,0,0)=(z,z,z)+(y-z,y-z,0)+(x-y,0,0)=(z+y-z+x-y,z+y-z,z)=(x,y,z) $.

To obtain this you need to find a, b, c and d such that $av_{1}+bv_{2}+cv_{2}+dv_{3}=(x,y,z)$

Clearly the vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$ since any arbitrary vector from $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be generated from these four vectors, however they do not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ since they are linearly dependent.

Comment: i still don't understand how the answer came up with the letters in front of v1, v2, v3, v4 which is z, (y-z), (x-y), 0 respectively :/

Comment: Solving a, b, c and d such that $av_{1}+bv_{2}+cv_{2}+dv_{3}=(x,y,z)$ we obtain $a+b+c+3d=x$, $a+b+2d=y$ and $a=z$ (where the last clearly follows since the vectors $v_{2}$, $v_{3}$ and $v_{4}$ have zero last term). Thus we know $a=z$, so what are the values of d, c and d?

Comment: thank you! i got it through the answer above, but thank you so much for your time